# How do I define a function detailing 30 days ago in ssrs?

Tags: ssrs-2016

I need to define a parameter default value in a function that describes 30 days ago using report builder. What would I put in my expression? I tried using `=Now()-30` but it returns the following error. [image: my error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bf0a961c-d21a-4153-a78b-6c06cdd2f50d/how-to-create-parameter-today-minus-some-number-of-days?forum=sqlreportingservices)

```
  =DateAdd("d", -30, Today())
```